# Implement pure virtual function with using

Tags: c++, pure-virtual

Consider the following program

```cpp
class Node {
public:
  virtual void Visit() = 0;
};

class Graph {
public:
  virtual void Visit();
};

class GraphNode1 : public Node, Graph {
};

class GraphNode2 : public Node, Graph {
    using Graph::Visit;
};

class GraphNode3 : public Node, Graph {
public:
    virtual void Visit() {
        Graph::Visit();
    }
};

int main()
{
  GraphNode1 a;
  GraphNode2 b;
  GraphNode3 c;
}
```

It does not compile, but complains that `GraphNode1` and `GraphNode2` are abstract, since `Node::Visit` is pure virtual.

I would have assumed that both `GraphNode1` and `GraphNode2` were fine, since:

- They contain an implementation of `Visit`.
- They contain only a single implementation of `Visit`, so there should be no ambiguity.

Can anyone explain why I have to create an explicit implementation to make it work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Node` and `Graph` are unrelated classes. Which makes `Node::Visit` and `Graph::Visit` distinct unrelated member functions.

Neither can override the other. You seem to think `Graph::Visit` is somehow "better" than `Node::Visit` on account of not being pure virtual, and should therefore override it. But there is no objective reason for it. For starters, pure virtual functions can have a definition:

```
struct A {
    virtual void thing() = 0;
};

inline void A::thing() {}
```

And secondly, a function can be **made pure virtual** when overriden:

```
struct A {
    virtual void thing() {}
};

struct B : A {
    void thing() override = 0;
};
```

So really, there is no reason for `Node::Visit` and `Graph::Visit` to interact as overriders of each other. That's why you need to be explicit and define a function yourslef that will serve as an overrider*.

---

* One shortcoming of C++ is that you in fact override *both* `Node::Visit` and `Graph::Visit` in `GraphNode3`. IMO it's a quirk of the language (really, it should be possible to keep them unrelated). MSVC has an extension that lets you choose what to override in a more fine-grained manner.

Comment: Is my suspicion correct that as they are both unrelated they both have individual pointers in the vtable which need to be set by individual implementations.

Comment: @Bart - Typically, yes